# React Navigation - Stack Navigation Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So i making a react app and there is a screen where i have a button on the right side of the header. The problem is that it crashes when clicked. Here is the code inside the react component (placed right above the constructor method):

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerRight: <Ionicons style={{marginRight: 15}} name={prefix + 'power'}
                    color={colors.app_secondary_color} size={30} onPress={() => this.signout()}/>
  }
```

And here is the error:

```
_this3.signout is not a function. (In '_this3.signout()', '_this3.signout' is undefined)

onPress
    ProfileView.js:25:80
```

i'm thinking the this reference doesn't reach that far?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `this.signout` because `navigationOptions` is static. You can achieve what you want by extracting the button into a different component and connecting it to the redux store, then dispatch a signout action onPress

Comment: thanks! i am trying to use firebase but i'll gladly add redux to my native app logic.